# Cargo install command fails with network error when trying to install a Rust crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm a beginner trying to set up a Rust project on my computer. I've installed Rust from the official website and I'm trying to install the `cargo-ndk` crate using the cargo install command, but I keep getting a network error. Here's the error message I see in my terminal:

```
Updating crates.io index
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): failed to send request: A connection with the server could not be established
; class=Os (2)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): failed to send request: A connection with the server could not be established
; class=Os (2)
error: failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  failed to send request: A connection with the server could not be established
  ; class=Os (2)
```

I've checked my internet connection, confirmed that GitHub is not blocked, and I don't have any active proxy settings. I'm not sure what else to try. How can I fix this issue and successfully install the cargo-ndk crate using cargo install?

Comment: Does this fix it? https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9335

Comment: Try prefixing the command with [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty), certain cargo commands are fidgety that way

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:4780
```

It worked for me.